# Meteor: Publish a collection and attach it to the appropriate user

Tags: meteor

I have a list of student users and collection of classes. When I publish the list of students I want it to display the classes they are attending. My code currently displays all the classes that every student is attending under each student instead of the classes that are relevant to the individual student.

How can I get it to display the right classes under the right stendents.

Path: `classes.js`

```
Template.classes.helpers({
    studentList: ()=> { 
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: { $ne: Meteor.userId() }}); 
    },      
    classes: ()=> {
        return Classes.find({_id: { $ne: Meteor.userId() }});
    },
});
```

Path: `classes.html`

```
{{#each studentList}}
    {{profile.firstName}}
        {{#each classes}}
            {{class}}
        {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Path: `Classes.js`

```
Schemas.Classes = new SimpleSchema({
    class: {
        type: String
    },
    teacherUserId: {
        type: String,
        autoValue: function() {
            return this.userId
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    },
    studentUserId: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: show us your `Class` and `Student` collection scheme

Comment: no problem. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are defining `classes: () => Classes.find({_id: { $ne: Meteor.userId() }})` what you are telling the computer is:

```
Every time I ask you for the box labeled 'classes' I want you to go 
through the box we called 'Classes' and fill 'classes' with everything
you find that doesn't have the '_id' property set to whatever you find
when you look inside of the box that 'Meteor.userId()' gives you.
```

That is not what you are wanting to ask your worker for. You want to ask your worker:

```
Every time I ask you for the box labeled 'classes' I want you to go
through the box we called 'Classes' and fill 'classes' with everything
that you find where the '_id' is set to a certain string that I am passing
you.
```

Which, without really trying to write it for you, it might have something to do with `this` being used somewhere in your [helper function](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/)

Comment: Thanks @tim. That's exactly what I was looking for. I'll add the answer below thanks again!

Comment: Awesome job dude! I was rushed for time and couldn't write up a code example before having to leave work. Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

The code above means: *"Find all classes where the id of the class isn't equal to the current user's id."* I think you want: *"Find all classes where the current user's id is in the list of students."*

Assuming classes have a `students` field, which is an array of user ids, you'd do this:

```js
return Classes.find({students: Meteor.userId()});
```

Comment: Hi @david thanks for your suggestion. I didn't mention above that this list is generated by the teacher. So Metewor.userId() doesn't seem to work

Comment: I still don't feel like there is enough information given to answer this. Can you show an example class document?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone's input my problem is solved! Tim hit the nail on the head. For those of you encountering a similar problem, check out the code below. I hope it helps. Thanks again Tim.

Path: `classes.js`

```
Template.classes.helpers({
    classes: ()=> {
        return JobOffers.findOne({candidateUserId: this._id});
    },
});
```

Path: `classes.html`

```
{{#each studentList}}
    {{profile.firstName}}
        {{#with classes}}
            {{class}}
        {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```